# How to use inline JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to create a popup in WordPress. My popup opened but cancel and send buttons are not working.

This is my script and code :

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        function launch() {
             $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }

        $('#try-1').click(function(e) {
            $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, preventScroll: true, onLoad: function() {
                $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }});

            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
    });
</script>
```

and this is my form

```
<a href="#" id="try-1" class="sprited"><div class="call"></div></a>
<div id="sign_up">
    <h3 id="see_id">Request a call Back</h3>
    <div id="sign_up_form">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="../mail.php" method="post" >
            <label><strong>Name :</strong> <input class="sprited"/></label>
            <label><strong>Mobile No :</strong> <input class="sprited"/></label>
            <div id="actions">
                <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="close form_button sprited" />
                <input type="button" name="send" value="Send" class="form_button sprited" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <a id="close_x" class="close sprited" href="#">close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wordpress doesn't really support inline javascript. If you view the source of the page you'll see that it get's sanitized by wordpress. Just put the javascript into a .js file somewhere and include it.

Comment: I have already created request.js file an include it in to header.php file. but it is not working

Comment: can you provide a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline javascript. As suggested by rosscower, add your javascript in a js file. You now need to [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it properly. Don't just dump it in the header. You will also need to think about [conditional statements](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) here to load your jquery file, if you only need to load it on a certain page you need to load it conditionally, otherwise this will load on all pages.

Example, you called your js file `myjs.js`and you add it in a folder called `js` and want to load it only on the homepage, you'll do something like this

```
function register_my_js() {
if(is_home()) {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myjs.js',    array(), '', true );
 }
}

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_js' );
```